# Ajuda com PHP em captura de dados.

Tags: php, log

Olá, tenho um determinado arquivo de log, e gostaria de capturar certos dados dele e armazenar em [].

veja o arquivo de log:

```
+++ Statistics Dump +++ (1499195839)
++ Incoming Requests ++
                 552 QUERY
++ Incoming Queries ++
                 546 A
                   1 NS
                   5 AAAA
++ Outgoing Queries ++
[View: default]
                1350 A
                  53 NS
                 446 AAAA
                 544 DS
                  35 DNSKEY
[View: _bind]
++ Name Server Statistics ++
                 552 IPv4 requests received
                   1 requests with EDNS(0) received
                 550 responses sent
                   1 responses with EDNS(0) sent
                 300 queries resulted in successful answer
                 541 queries resulted in non authoritative answer
                   6 queries resulted in nxrrset
                   9 queries resulted in SERVFAIL
                 235 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
                 385 queries caused recursion
                   2 duplicate queries received
++ Zone Maintenance Statistics ++
++ Resolver Statistics ++
[Common]
```

Agora via php gostaria de pegar por exemplo a 3 linha o dado 552 e imprimir assim: 
[552].

Obrigado.

Comment: É só isto mesmo ou vai precisar pegar mais coisas, como os detalhes a frente do numero e dividir a cada `++` em um item de um array "multidimensional"?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se eu conseguisse assim: 
[552] query
[546] A
[1] NS
[5]AAAA

já está de bom tamanho.

Comment: Tá ok, mas só vai precisar do 552 ou vai precisar dividir em blocos para cada "grupo" (que usou o sinal de `++`)? Por exemplo: `++ Incoming Queries ++` seria um grupo e `++ Incoming Requests ++` seria outro.

Comment: vou precisar do 552. Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `regex` com `preg_match_all` e ler linha por linha, a regex deve ficar assim (mais ou menos, pode ajustar):

```
\s+(\d{1,3})\s[^\n]+\n

^   ^       ^  ^   ^
|   |       |  |   |
|   |       |  |   |
|   |       |  |   +--- Procura a quebra de linha (para separar os resultados)
|   |       |  |
|   |       |  +---Procura qualquer coisa que não seja quebra de linha
|   |       |  
|   |       +-- Verifica se há um espaço após o numero
|   |       
|   +-- Pega o numero (o parenteses é para separar e um novo `match`)
|   
+------ procura qualquer espaço até achar o numero
```

Código deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
$foo = file_get_contents('meulog.log');

if (preg_match_all('#\s+(\d{1,3})\s[^\n]+\n#', $foo, $matches)) {
    $retornou = $matches[1];
    print_r($retornou); //Exibe todos numeros que pegou
} else {
    echo 'Nada encontrado';
}
```

Exemplo online no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/02DMCp), código:

```
<?php
$foo = '+++ Statistics Dump +++ (1499195839)
++ Incoming Requests ++
                 552 QUERY
++ Incoming Queries ++
                 546 A
                   1 NS
                   5 AAAA
++ Outgoing Queries ++
[View: default]
                1350 A
                  53 NS
                 446 AAAA
                 544 DS
                  35 DNSKEY
[View: _bind]
++ Name Server Statistics ++
                 552 IPv4 requests received
                   1 requests with EDNS(0) received
                 550 responses sent
                   1 responses with EDNS(0) sent
                 300 queries resulted in successful answer
                 541 queries resulted in non authoritative answer
                   6 queries resulted in nxrrset
                   9 queries resulted in SERVFAIL
                 235 queries resulted in NXDOMAIN
                 385 queries caused recursion
                   2 duplicate queries received
++ Zone Maintenance Statistics ++
++ Resolver Statistics ++
[Common]';

if (preg_match_all('#\s+(\d{1,3})\s[^\n]+\n#', $foo, $matches)) {
    $retornou = $matches[1];
    print_r($retornou); //Exibe todos numeros que pegou
} else {
    echo 'Nada encontrado';
}
```

O exemplo retorna isto:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 552
    [1] => 546
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 53
    [5] => 446
    [6] => 544
    [7] => 35
    [8] => 552
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 550
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 300
    [13] => 541
    [14] => 6
    [15] => 9
    [16] => 235
    [17] => 385
    [18] => 2
)
```

Basta iterar com um `for` ou `while`

> Perfeito, porem com faz pra eu deixar o resultado dentro do [] por
>   exemplo:
>
> 0=> [552] 1=> [546]

Pode usar o `array_map` ou um `for` normal, exemplo:

```
if (preg_match_all('#\s+(\d{1,3})\s[^\n]+\n#', $foo, $matches)) {
    $retornou = array_map(function ($value) {
        //Adiciona os colchetes (parênteses retos)
        return '[' . $value . ']';
    }, $matches[1]);

    print_r($retornou); //Exibe todos numeros que pegou
} else {
    echo 'Nada encontrado';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perfeito, porem com faz pra eu deixar o resultado dentro do []
por exemplo:

`0=> [552]
1=> [546]`

Comment: Esse `[...]` é string ou quer que os numeros fiquem dentro de arrays?

Comment: Editei a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217983/3635